# C# add function dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic, macros

I have a program with some kind of "Macro Manager" that can (or at least should) save and play macros - one after the other. The macros are functions that the user can select by himself.

For example if the user wants to create a new macro he is going to do the following steps:

1. Click Button "Create"
2. Click Button "Select function"
3. Click another Button (The button holds a function behind it)
4. Play the macro

So as you can see, the user should be able to choose which function he wants to use dynamically.

I tried using delegates, but I dont really understand them (even though I have read about it)

So this is my code:

The MacroManager (Which holds the macros and plays them one after the other):

```
namespace ControlCenter
{
    public class ControlCenterMacroManager
    {
        public List<ControlCenterMacro> macroList = new List<ControlCenterMacro>();
        public string macroName;

        public void runMacroList()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(runMacroList_t));
            t.Start();
        }

        public void runMacroList_t()
        {
            foreach (ControlCenterMacro macro in macroList)
            {
                Console.Write("Playing Macro: ");
                macro.Run();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This would be the macro:

```
namespace ControlCenter
{
    public class ControlCenterMacro
    {
        public bool isTimeout=false;
        public int timemilli=0;
        public delegate int macroAction();
        public macroAction action;

        public void Run()
        {
            if (isTimeout)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting " + timemilli + " milliseconds ");
                Thread.Sleep(timemilli / 4);
                Console.Write(".");
                Thread.Sleep(timemilli / 4);
                Console.Write(".");
                Thread.Sleep(timemilli / 4);
                Console.Write(".");
                Thread.Sleep(timemilli / 4);
                Console.WriteLine(" done");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Playing action " + action.ToString());
                action();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is one of the possible functions I want to lay behind it (which is located in another class in another project):

```
public int turnOn()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Einschalten:");
    if(HomeMaticHttpRequest.sendRequest(this.url + "statechange.cgi?ise_id=" + this.RecieverId + "&new_value=true")!=null)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this problem without too much hardcoding? (Want to keep it relatively dynamical)

Comment: Are the macros predefined functions? Should the user set any parameters for the macro?

Comment: what are the restrictions for the possible functions? do they have a return value? or are some of type void? do they have parameters?

Comment: You can even use pure C# for your scripts, you can use the CodeDom to generate on-the-fly code, compile it in an assembly and store it to be able to reuse as many times as you want.

Comment: was my answer general enough or do you still need it more general ?

Comment: @MongZhu sorry that I didnt answer - didnt have a laptop for a week. This answer helped a lot so yeah dont need it more general atm :) ty for helping me

Comment: cool, glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example stripped down to its essentials.

The Macro:

```
public class Macro
{
    public delegate int macroAction();
    public macroAction action;

    public void Run()
    {
        action();
    }    
}
```

A container class with different methods:

```
public class Container
{
    public int turnOn()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Einschalten");
        return 1;
    }

    public int turnOff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ausschalten");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And a small test programm which assigns different methods:

```
void Main()
{       
    Container c = new Container();

    List<Macro> MacroList = new List<Macro>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Macro m = new Macro();
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            m.action = c.turnOn;
        }
        else
        {
            m.action = c.turnOff;
        }

        MacroList.Add(m);
    }

    foreach (var m in MacroList)
    {
        m.Run();
    }       
}
```

For the more general version I have to comeback tomorrow, gotta catch my train ;)